# Multiple for loops in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program that will factor any trinomial of the form ax^2+bx+c, but I'm kind of stuck. I've got a sequence of 4 for loops that looks like this:

```
print "Factoring...\n"

for i in range(low_value, high_value):
    for j in range(low_value, high_value):
        for k in range(low_value, high_value):
            for l in range(low_value, high_value):
                print "testing\n"
                if i*k==a & j*l==c & (i*l)+(j*k)==b:
                    print "Your factored Equation is: (" + i + "x + " + j + ")(" + k + "x + " + l + ")"
                else:
                    print "No solution found.\n"
print "testing...\n"
```

Anyways I know the code is far from optimal but nothing inside the for loops are executing. The "testing..." message at the end is displayed but nothing is printed before that(by that I mean the "testing", "Your factored equation is:", or the "No solution found"). Is there some kind of limitation in Python where I can't use so many for loops at once? Is there something wrong with my syntax that I just am unable to see? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: How do you define `low_value` and `high_value`?

Comment: If you assign a value to low_value and high_value, your code does in fact do `print "testing"`, so there doesn't seem to be any problem with the loops.

Comment: Syntax-wise, you should use the `and` keyword in place of `&` in your `if` statement.

Comment: low_value and high_value are the highest and lowest from a, b, c in the expression ax^2+bx+c

Comment: Here's the output I'm getting:

>>> 
Enter the leading coefficient of the Trinomial: 
30
Enter the middle coefficient of the Trinomial: 
1
Enter the final value of the Trinomial: 
12
Factoring...

testing...

>>>

Comment: You haven't posted the code which prompts for the input. I'd guess something weird is going on there.

Comment: As an aside, are you familiar with the quadratic formula?  This factoring can be done without any loops, which will make it *far* faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the question stated, there are a few problems with the code: :-)

- Given low_value of -1000 and high_value of 1000, "testing" and "no solution has been found" will be printed ~16 trillion times.
- Execution doesn't stop when a solution is found.
- `print` as statement restricts the code to Python2, it is recommended to use the `print(stuff)` function instead.
- `print` automatically inserts a newline. `\n` is not needed.

Here's a suggested rewrite:

```
def factor(a, b, c):
    low_value = min(a, b, c)
    high_value = max(a, b, c)
    for i in range(low_value, high_value):
        for j in range(low_value, high_value):
            for k in range(low_value, high_value):
                if i*k != a:
                    # check this clause earlier to improve speed a bit
                    continue
                for l in range(low_value, high_value):
                    if j*l != c:
                        continue
                    if (i*l) + (j*k) != b:
                        continue
                    return (i, j, k, l)
    return None

print("Factoring...")
solution = factor(1, 2, 4)
if solution:
    (i, j, k, l) = solution
    print("Your factored Equation is: (" + i + "x + " + j + ")" +
          "(" + k + "x + " + l + ")")
else:
    print("No solution can be found.")
```

Comment: Yeah I hadn't quite gotten all the parts of the code in the right place yet, I just wanted to make sure all the logic was working properly before. But thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski it's a typo for "None".  Derp.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `and` for logical conjunction, not '&' symbol.
Try this:

```
...
if (i*k==a) and (j*l==c) and ((i*l+j*k)==b):
...
```

Comment: this is just a "better programming practice" not a syntax error

Comment: @SpiXel: While it isn't a *syntax* error it still is an error, since `&` is *bitwise* and.

Comment: @SpiXel: Not only is `&` bitwise instead of Boolean, it has a higher precedence than `==`, whereas `and` has a lower precedence.  At the Python prompt, try `4==4 & 3==3` and then try `4==4 and 3==3`.

Comment: @sth yes you're right , but still , considering boolean values being checked , is there still any differences ?

Comment: @JohnY That precedence does it, so it makes a difference there. Thanks

Comment: Oh I didn't know it made a difference. I'm used to C++ where I always use '&&' and '||'. That seems to have a done the trick though :)

Comment: @TylerJarjoura you can also try `all()`, `if all((i*k==a,j*l==c,(i*l)+(j*k)==b))`

Answer (score 0):

To make it more pythonic:

```
from itertools import product

for i, j, k, l in product(range(low, high), repeat=4):
    print i, j, k, l
```